# combine two images and save as single in android as well as at its current position in imageview

Tags: image, save

I m creating photo frame application and i got two images, one is for frame from imagelist array and another from my gallery. i've drag this image in frame but now i cant save this two images as single one and also with their current size and position.

I ve set frame(drawable) as imageview and uploaded image is conveted into bitmap.

i've also tried with canvas but its not working...
My code is:

`if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
        if (extras2 != null) {
        photo= extras2.getParcelable("data");

```
    imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

    }
    }
       resultbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame.getWidth(),frame.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    canvas= new Canvas(resultbitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(photo, 0, 0, null);
    frame.draw(canvas);

    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
                try {
                       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                       resultbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Image:"+fname+"is stored in saved_images Folder in sd card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       out.flush();
                       out.close();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
    }`
```

plz give some solution ...i'm trying from long time...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making the mistake by writing the canvas into the frame bitmap.

```
frame.draw(canvas);
```

Just write your 'frame' bitmap into the canvas the same way you wrote the 'photo' bitmap.

```
canvas= new Canvas(resultbitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(photo, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(frame, 0, 0, null);
```